# How to prevent Qt Creator Debugger console from popping up

Tags: qt, debugging, qt-creator

During debug in QtCreator 4.6.2 (I debug QML) the QtCreator debugger console (view #5) constantly pops up. My debugging tasks typically rely on log analysis and such distractions heavily decrease productivity.

Surprisingly I could not find any related option in Tools -> Options -> Debugger pane. Is it possible anyway?